# sanitize-html vs encodeURIComponent URL to prevent Reflected XSS attack in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xss, sanitization, encodeuricomponent

I want to prevent my app against Reflected XSS attack caused by passing scripts in url like :

```
https://www.myapp.com/profile/?year=2020<script>alert('Boo!');<!--
```

What would be the best way to tackle this?

I am parsing each query param and validating against a regex and in case it passes the test, I return its encoded value using encodeURIComponent for additional layer of security. Is it enough or I need to sanitise it for better security?

My current way:

```
(regexForYear.test(year) && encodeURIComponent(year)) || 2020
```

Comment: `year=\x32\x30\x32\x30`

Comment: If it is just an integer why not cast it as such?

Comment: @ritesh - what would you like to recommend to overcome all such flaws?

Comment: @user3783243 it’s just an example.

Comment: I don't get what the point of `encodeURIComponent` would be here. You should `decodeURIComponent` the url parameter, and *then* html-sanitise (or escape) it.

Comment: Decoding it will inject the script as is and will lead to injection. Encoding will transform characters like < hence nullifying their meaning. @bergi

Comment: @VishalGulati using Regex is excellent way and more secure. Searching for specific length is also would great work. Like in year, `if((/^[0-9]{4}$/).test(year))`. just test for valid numbers.

Comment: @VishalGulati But it will transform them into an URL, not to html. Don't use the wrong tool for the job!